# Checkbox not checked when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactable table in a React class  which contains checkboxes for each row. When a checkbox is clicked it fires click event taking the data from row to be processed.

The problem. I am experiencing is that the checkbox is not remaining checked when clicked even though I am getting data. So, I am asking whether some can help me. I have provided the main code snippet:

Checkbox row has the following

```
check={this.checkrows.indexOf(index) }
click={this.clickrow.bind(null,row,index)}
```

The method is:

```
clicking(row,index){

    let checkrows = this.state.checkrows;
    let data = this.state.data.mydata;

    if (event.target.checked){
      if(checkrows.indexOf(index) ===-1){
            checkrows.push(row)
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you omit `setState` from your `clicking` example?

Comment: There is a Seascape method at the end but I have omitted this in order to focus on the problem

Comment: Sorry replying via a predictive text mobile phone.  It should say setstate method

Comment: Ok, it would help to see how `setState` is connected to the code. If the click handler doesn't commit the data, I don't see how it could work. Just `push`ing isn't enough unless you commit. I would write something like `this.setState({checkrows: checkrows.concat(row)})` instead of `push`myself.

Comment: If you don't know why it isn't working, then omitting code to "focus on the problem" is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, on the setState I did setState ( checkrows:checkrows)};

Comment: If I alter checkrows.push(index), the checkbox keeps its check state but the checkrows only of course contains the index not the data I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup, you are (maybe inadvertently) mutating state, and you really shouldn't.

- `let checkrows = this.state.checkrows;` makes checkrows point to state.
- later on: `checkrows.push()` mutates `checkrows`
- but since `checkrows` points to state, you are now directly mutating state.

And react does not like that/ explicitly forbids you to mutate state directly.

Better:

```
clicking(row,index){
  // add slice() to make a copy of the checkrows in state
  let checkrows = this.state.checkrows.slice();
  // same for data (although not used in your example)
  let data = this.state.data.mydata.slice();

  if (event.target.checked){
    if(checkrows.indexOf(index) === -1){
      // pushing new row is now done in copy, not in state directly
      checkrows.push(row);
      // followed by properly setting new state
      this.setState( { checkrows : checkrows });
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the bit `checkrow.indexOf(index)` is a bit odd: if you want to check if a certain object is part of an array, your can use `.indexOf(myObject)`. But you cannot use this to check whether an index (usually a number 0 or 1 or 2 etc) is part of an array. Maybe `index` is actually the object, not the index number. But then I suggest to rename this to `rowobject` or something to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the state of your component, also your usage of an array is a little confusing, if you want to access elements directly it's easier to use an object.

I wrote a small sample that should look like what you're currently writing, but it's hard to figure out what your components are based on the code you gave. Try this: http://jsbin.com/yarehemuwo/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks, but our data is a complex json which we bind to a reactable table by writing data.map(row) and setting columns by writing row.somedata. I have only supplied a small snippet of the code